# Add and view dataLabels (CTDLbls) in lineChart excel graph

Tags: excel, graph, apache-poi

I've developed the following code, but is not **fully acomplishing what I need**.

I would like to have the chance to set some specific datalabels of this serie

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet dataSheet = wb.createSheet("linechart");

        final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 10;
        final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 4;

        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
            row = dataSheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
                if (colIndex<3) {
                    cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
                    cell.setCellValue(rowIndex * ((colIndex + 1) + ((int) (Math.random() * 10))));
                }
                else{
                    if (rowIndex == 0){
                        cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
                        cell.setCellValue("This is the first comment");
                    }
                    else if (rowIndex == 3){
                        cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
                        cell.setCellValue("This is another comment");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Drawing drawing = dataSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 2, 3, NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 15, 20);

        //XSSFChart xlsxChart = XSSFChart.createChart();
        Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
        ChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
        legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT);


        LineChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();

        ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
        leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

        ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, NUM_OF_ROWS - 1, 0, 0));
        ChartDataSource<Number> ys1 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, NUM_OF_ROWS - 1, 1, 1));
        ChartDataSource<Number> ys2 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, NUM_OF_ROWS - 1, 2, 2));
        // Not used: ChartDataSource<String> ys3 = DataSources.fromStringCellRange(dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, NUM_OF_ROWS - 1, 3, 3));

        LineChartSeries series1 = data.addSeries(xs, ys1);
        series1.setTitle("one");
        LineChartSeries series2 = data.addSeries(xs, ys2);
        series2.setTitle("two");

        chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);  // creating the basics of the graph

        XSSFChart xssfChart = (XSSFChart) chart;
        CTPlotArea plotArea = xssfChart.getCTChart().getPlotArea();

        CTBoolean ctBool = CTBoolean.Factory.newInstance();
        ctBool.setVal(true);
        plotArea.getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls().setShowVal(ctBool);
        plotArea.getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowLeaderLines();
        plotArea.getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowLeaderLines(ctBool);
        ctBool.setVal(false);
        plotArea.getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowSerName(ctBool);
        plotArea.getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowPercent(ctBool);
        plotArea.getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowLegendKey(ctBool);
        plotArea.getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowCatName(ctBool);
        plotArea.getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowLeaderLines(ctBool);
        plotArea.getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setShowBubbleSize(ctBool);

        // Adding "markers" on each point
        CTMarker ctMarker = CTMarker.Factory.newInstance();
        ctMarker.setSymbol(CTMarkerStyle.Factory.newInstance());
        for (CTLineSer ser : plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSerArray()) {
            ser.setMarker(ctMarker);
        }

        try{
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:" + File.separator + "stack_v2.xlsx");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Generating the following output
[Output from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH4lb.png)

But what I want, is having the showLeaderLines option activated inside the CDTLbsls structure

See the following **desired output:**

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrHkb.png)

I need help on:

- Clarifying Apache-POI classes involved (CDTLbl, CDTLbls, CTLine, DLbl & DLbls)
- How to achieved the ShowLeaderLines functionality
- How to set specific content rather than the value
- Located them at a specific point of the graph (as you may see, I would like to add it close to the top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I find it was not possible to achieve the same functionality as with MS Office 2016 because the libs are not enough developed.

Ways tried between others was modifying directly the XML output... but some tags are not available yet.